# Is Motel really a "blend of motor and hotel" developed in the 1920s?

Tags: etymology

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motel)

> History and Etymology for motel
>
> blend of motor and hotel

Is this supported by its earliest known uses?

Comment: Have you a reason for doubting it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, not really. I just want to see it used as such. If that's OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many sources, including the Smithsonian, say that the first use of "motel" was when an architect and developer, Arthur Heinemann, built a hotel aimed at motor travellers in San Luis Obispo, California (USA), in 1925. He shortened the phrase "motor hotel" in calling it the "Milestone Mo-tel", and the term went into general use, shedding the hyphen**, as motor travel, and the need for overnight accommodation for motorists, increased in the 20th century.

[World's first motel](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/worlds-first-motel-was-luxury-establishment-not-dive-180961384/)

** Perhaps it was left behind in a Mo-tel; [lots of things](https://www.gardenweb.com/discussions/2498701/hotel-industry-questions-about-lost-and-found) are.